# Write a program which reads a word and determines how many words, with the same number of letters as the input, it might represent

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, morse-code

This is a part of Morse code problem. I want to figure out how many words can be made from the encoded Morse code ensuring the word that is made would be of same length as input.

```
morseCode = {"A":".-","B":"-...","C":"-.-."}
morseCode["D"] = "-.."
morseCode["E"] = "."
morseCode["F"] = "..-."
morseCode["G"] = "--."
morseCode["H"] = "...."
morseCode["I"] = ".."
morseCode["J"] = ".---"
morseCode["K"] = "-.-"
morseCode["L"] = ".-.."
morseCode["M"] = "--"
morseCode["N"] = "-."
morseCode["O"] = "---"
morseCode["P"] = ".--."
morseCode["Q"] = "--.-"
morseCode["R"] = ".-."
morseCode["S"] = "..."
morseCode["T"] = "-"
morseCode["U"] = "..-"
morseCode["V"] = "...-"
morseCode["W"] = ".--"
morseCode["X"] = "-..-"
morseCode["Y"] = "-.--"
morseCode["Z"] = "--.."

#Retrieve end-user's message and convert it to upper case.
message = input("Type a message to convert in morse code (e.g. \"SOS\"?)").upper()
encodedMessage = ""

#Convert each letter into Morse code:
for character in message:
  #Check that the character is in the Morse Code dictionary (e.g letter of the alphabet)
  if character in morseCode:
    encodedMessage += morseCode[character] 
  else:
    #Replace unrecognised characters with a space
    encodedMessage += ""

#Display the message in Morse code:
print("Your message in Morse code is:")
print(encodedMessage)
```

> Input : eta
>
> Your message in Morse Code is : **.-.-**
>
> Output : 3

As 3 words of the same length as eta can be made with the encoded Morse code. (eta,ent,aet)

I'm not able to figure out how to find the number of words that can be made with the Morse code.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this without optimizing:

```
morseCode = {
    "A": ".-",
    "B": "-...",
    "C": "-.-.",
    "D": "-..",
    "E": ".",
    "F": "..-.",
    "G": "--.",
    "H": "....",
    "I": "..",
    "J": ".---",
    "K": "-.-",
    "L": ".-..",
    "M": "--",
    "N": "-.",
    "O": "---",
    "P": ".--.",
    "Q": "--.-",
    "R": ".-.",
    "S": "...",
    "T": "-",
    "U": "..-",
    "V": "...-",
    "W": ".--",
    "X": "-..-",
    "Y": "-.--",
    "Z": "--.."
}

def countWords(msg, length, collected = ''):
    if not msg:
        if not length:
            return [collected]
        return []
    current = []
    for letter, code in morseCode.items():
        if msg.startswith(code):
            current.extend(countWords(msg[len(code):], length - 1, collected + letter))
    return current

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #Retrieve end-user's message and convert it to upper case.
    message = input('Type a message to convert in morse code (e.g. "SOS"): ').upper()
    encodedMessage = ""

    #Convert each letter into morse code:
    for character in message:
      #Check that the character is in the moreCode dictionary (e.g letter of the alphabet)
      if character in morseCode:
        encodedMessage += morseCode[character] 
      else:
        #Replace unrecognised characters with a space
        encodedMessage += ""

    #Display the message in morse code:
    print("Your message in morse code is:", encodedMessage)

    matches = countWords(encodedMessage, len(message))
    print("There are", len(matches), "that match:")
    for word in matches:
        print(word)
```

and your example:

```
>py bla.py
Type a message to convert in morse code (e.g. "SOS"): ent
Your message in morse code is: .-.-
There are 3 that match:
AET
ENT
ETA
```